# dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, virtualenv

A while ago I had both Python 2.7 and 3.5 installed on my Mac and was able to use them both successfully. Not too long ago, I installed Anaconda and IPython. I have used those for a couple weeks for prototyping and in-console programming.

After I went back to the regular Python for my Django and Flask projects, I discovered an unpleasant thing. Namely, whenever I try to run `python` or `python3` I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
  Referenced from: /Users/name/anaconda3/bin/python3
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

When I run `conda` I also get the same error.

If I create a new virtual environment with `virtualenv django-project`, I am able to activate it, and it allows me to run Python 2.7 successfully.

My question is the following: How can I fix `python` and `python3` for the command line while also retaining the working Anaconda and IPython? How can I make sure that the virtual environments are able to carry Python 3?

Comment: Did you find the solution to this.

Comment: Yes, follow the discussion here. I currently have Miniconda installed and `source` it each time I want to use `Python`, period. What's more, I created a new virtual env in miniconda that contains everything I need for IPython. If I want to use IPython, then I simply switch to that virtual env and off I go. Two commands is not bad.

Comment: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/305#issuecomment-285094497

Answer (score 1):

I also use macOS and I never mess with or even deal with the system python.  I've installed python3 via Homebrew (https://brew.sh) and I always use a virtual environment.  I have one in my home directory (my default) and I have one for each project I'm working on.

Your rule of thumb should be to never run 'pip' if you aren't within a virtualenv.  Check with `$ echo $VIRTUAL_ENV`.

To create/recreate the virtual environment in python3 with the currently installed libraries:

- Get into your project directory and active your virtualenv.
- (optional) Dump your requirements via pip: `$ pip freeze > requirements.txt`
- Nuke your virtual environment directory if you have one: `$ rm -rf .venv`
- Deactivate it: `$ deactivate`
- Create a new one with python3: `$ virtualenv -p python3 .venv`
- Activate it: `$ source .venv/bin/activate`
- (optional) Install your requirements: `$ pip install -r requirements.txt`
- Profit.

You can skip the steps for writing and reading the requirements.txt if you just want to create a new virtual environment and then install only the modules you want/need later.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, to reduce your confusion n which python you are using you could try the following 2 commands in Linux or mac where bash shell is installed:

$ which python
or
$ which python3

in my case, it outputs the python paths I am using with pyenv [with fish shell] [$ is a shell sign]

[image]